# Error: Cannot create instance of <the-contract>; no code at address 0x

Tags: solidity, truffle, uniswap, ganache

I'm using truffle and I want to use USDC token contract to send token to a address but it shows me this error when I run `npx truffle migrate`

```
Error: Cannot create instance of ERC20Mock; no code at address 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48
```

although the address is correct and contract has code in `mainnet`
here is how I use it

```
const Dex = artifacts.require("Dex");
const ERC20Mock = artifacts.require("ERC20Mock");

const USDC_MAINNET = "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48";
const UNLOCKED_ACCOUNT = "<THE_ACCOUNT>";

module.exports = async function (deployer, networks, accounts) {
  const usdc = await ERC20Mock.at(USDC_MAINNET);
  console.log(accounts);
  // Create Dex Contract with 10 ether from the deployer account
  await deployer.deploy(Dex, {
    from: accounts[0],
    value: "10000000000000000000",
  });

  const dex = await Dex.deployed();

  // Transfer USDC from unlocked account to Dex Contract
  await usdc.transfer(dex.address, 10000000000, {
    from: UNLOCKED_ACCOUNT,
  });

  // Transfer USDC from unlocked account to user account
  await usdc.transfer(accounts[1], 10000000000, {
    from: UNLOCKED_ACCOUNT,
  });
};
```

#### update:

Here is ERC20Mock solidity code

```
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract ERC20Mock is ERC20 {
  constructor() public ERC20('USDC Coin', 'USDC') {}
}
```

and here is the new code

```
const Dex = artifacts.require("Dex");
const ERC20Mock = artifacts.require("ERC20Mock");

const USDC_MAINNET = "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48";
const UNLOCKED_ACCOUNT = "0x6262998ced04146fa42253a5c0af90ca02dfd2a3";

module.exports = async function (deployer, networks, accounts) {
  console.log(accounts);
  // Create Dex Contract with 10 ether from the deployer account
  await deployer.deploy(Dex, {
    from: accounts[0],
    value: "10000000000000000000",
  });
  await deployer.deploy(ERC20Mock, {
    from: accounts[0],
    value: "10000000000000000000",
  });

  const usdc = await ERC20Mock.deployed();
  const dex = await Dex.deployed();

  // Transfer USDC from unlocked account to Dex Contract
  await usdc.transfer(dex.address, 10000000000, {
    from: UNLOCKED_ACCOUNT,
  });

  // Transfer USDC from unlocked account to user account
  await usdc.transfer(accounts[1], 10000000000, {
    from: UNLOCKED_ACCOUNT,
  });
};
```

Here is the error I got

```
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"ERC20Mock" hit a require or revert statement somewhere in its constructor. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all require conditions.
   * Adding reason strings to your require statements.
```

Answer (score 0):

The USDC contract is on Mainnet. But most probably, you are trying to deploy it on local network.
Instead, copy code of USDC and deploy on you local network similar to what you are doing now. And use deployed address of USDC from local network for you use

Comment: it shows me "ERC20Mock" hit a require or revert statement somewhere in its constructor. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all require conditions.
   * Adding reason strings to your require statements.

Comment: I added ERC20MMock code in the question

Comment: I tried to deploy the contract exactly like I deployed the DEX

Comment: @YahyaParvar can you try this

 await deployer.deploy(Dex, {
    from: accounts[0]
  });

Comment: I tried that and I got the error

Comment: let me put the new code as well

Comment: Ok I added the new code please have a look at it

Comment: 1. Please show the error. Are you sure you are getting error in constructor. 
2. Before transfering tokens. Have you minted tokens. Is you balance more than what you are trying to transfer.
3. You were trying to use usdc mainnet and not mock USDC. I guess you just fixed it.

Comment: thanks for your time:) I added the error to the question

Comment: I'm running ganache locally and forking the mainnet

Comment: Will be helpful if you could show me what account can I put in ganache configuration for `unlocked_accounts`

Comment: This is the tutorial that I want to implement I think this might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q79VxwKqeaU&t=79s

Comment: can you try adding payable keyword in both contracts Dex and ERC20Mock


```constructor() public```    ```payable``` ```ERC20('USDC Coin', 'USDC') {}```

Comment: can you share your repo. So i can look deeper into it